# Stops audio AVPlayer on iPhone sleep (iOS6, iPhone5)

Tags: iphone, ios, avplayer

If someone has experienced this issue, that would be great to hear from.

So here is a case scenario when the audio stops working:

- Load app, start playing
- Exit the app
- The phone goes to grey mode, then sleeps
- Audio stops playing
- Uunlocked the phone
- Bring the app back
- Stream loads back

Comment: Do you want the audio too keep playing even if the iPhone goes to sleep mode??

Comment: So ??? What is your problem ?

Comment: Yes. Just image a basic radio app, that plays audio, think from a user point of view, what happens if the user is walking or in the bed listenening to the music?

Comment: @Maulik, the problem is that stream / audio stops playing

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771105/how-do-i-get-my-avplayer-to-play-while-app-is-in-background