# How to play audio in background with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation

As you see I'm streaming an audio broadcast. But when I press the home button and exit the app streaming stops or I cannot hear. How can I continue streaming in background and listen it from lock screen?

ViewController.Swift

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer
import GoogleMobileAds


    class ViewController: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate {
    
        @IBOutlet weak var exitMapButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var radarMap: UIWebView!
        var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
        func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
            var interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "adUnitID-XXXX")
            interstitial.delegate = self
            interstitial.loadRequest(GADRequest())
            return interstitial
        }
        
        func getAd(){
            if (self.interstitial.isReady)
            {
                self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
                self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadInterstitial()
            }
        }
        @IBOutlet weak var ataturkButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var sabihaButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var esenbogaButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var weatherButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var webViewButton: UIButton!
        var googleBannerView: GADBannerView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }
class PlayerAv {
            var audioLink: String?
            var player: AVPlayer
            init(link: String) {
                self.audioLink = link
                self.player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: link))
            }
        }
        var myPlayer = PlayerAv(link: "http://somewebsite.com/abc.pls")
        var setTowerState = ""
        
        @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
            var currentValue = Float(sender.value)
            println(currentValue)
            myPlayer.player.volume = currentValue
        }
        @IBAction func getWeatherWindow(sender: AnyObject) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://somewebpage.com")!)
            println("Directed to weather page")
        }
        @IBAction func changeToAtaturk() {
            myPlayer.player.pause()
            myPlayer = PlayerAv(link: "http://somewebsite.com/abc.pls")
            myPlayer.audioLink == ""
            println("\(myPlayer.audioLink!)--a")
            playButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            myPlayer.player.play()
            setTowerState = "ataturk"
            statusLabel.text = "Status: Playing, LTBA"
        }
        @IBAction func changeToEsenboga() {
            myPlayer.player.pause()
            myPlayer = PlayerAv(link: "http://somewebsite.com/def.pls")
            println("\(myPlayer.audioLink!)--a")
            playButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            myPlayer.player.play()
            setTowerState = "esenboga"
            statusLabel.text = "Status: Playing, LTAC"
        }
        @IBAction func changeToSabiha() {
            myPlayer.player.pause()
            myPlayer = PlayerAv(link: "http://somewebsite.com/efg.pls")
            println("\(myPlayer.audioLink!)--a")
            playButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            myPlayer.player.play()
            setTowerState = "sabiha"
            statusLabel.text = "Status: Playing, LTFJ"
        }
        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }
        @IBAction func playButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
            toggle()
        }
        func toggle() {
            if playButton.titleLabel?.text == "Play" {
                playRadio()
                println("Playing")
                statusLabel.text = "Status: Playing"
            } else {
                pauseRadio()
                println("Paused")
                statusLabel.text = "Status: Paused"
            }
        }
        func playRadio() {
            myPlayer.player.play()
            playButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)   
        }
        func pauseRadio() {
            myPlayer.player.pause()
            playButton.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You need to set your app Capabilities Background Modes (Audio and AirPlay) and set your AVAudioSession category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback and set it active

**From Xcode 11.4 • Swift 5.2**

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
    print("Playback OK")
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    print("Session is Active")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

[image]

Comment: @LeoDabus where do we put that code? I added that to the viewDidLoad and app delegate and it didn't work. Confused as to where it should go?

Comment: @lukeslvi anywhere before you try to start playing your audio.

Comment: Hey @LeoDabus it still turns off. I'm adding it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath as well as in the App Delegate and it's not working. I also added it in the custom cell without any luck. Any ideas what could be wrong? Btw, I'm using YouTubeSDK, but I'm assuming that sound is sound and it doesn't matter. Please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: it is not the same. You can't play video in the background.

Comment: But what about just the sound? @LeoDabus

Comment: What do you mean? When playing the YouTube video or? I posted a question earlier (so it doesn't conflict with this question) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029098/playing-youtubeplayer-sound-in-background-swift @LeoDabus Btw, when I press home and then use the drag up menu to play the music it plays. So it's possible, it's about changing the state. I'm just not sure how to do that...

Comment: @LeoDabus I was using EZAudio, and trying to play an audio. when I go background player stop. and I cannot play any audio after that, Any idea?

Comment: If you are streaming, you also must add the "App downloads content from the network" to the capabilities / required background modes

Comment: This solution works for me. By chance while the audio was playing an alert on my phone went off (alarm of default clock app) which stopped the audio. Is there a way to avoid even alerts from interrupting the audio? Thx

Comment: @Leo Dabus, thanks for your response, the code (so quick) and follow up. I'm trying to implement now and will respond with results. The option == .shouldResume is giving me a compile error saying == cannot be applied to operand of AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptions and '_'

Comment: @Leo Dabus, thx for follow up. I tried to add observer thus: let theSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.handleInterruption(_:)), name: AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification, object: theSession)
 But when my alarm goes off the console is not showing "began" or "ended"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120293/discussion-between-rockhammer-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: Perfect! But used to delete "with: .mixWithOthers", otherwise control center buttons on a lock screen disappeared. try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)

Comment: Hello How can i set all details like song name , song thumb image on lock screen as well as bottom swipe menu

Comment: @LeoDabus I am running your code in viewDidLoad. It plays in the background, but it does not show any controls to play/stop when screen is locked. What am I missing here? https://imgur.com/he8ZUBu

Comment: Man, running into this with XCode 12. No end in sight. Have tried everything imaginable.

Comment: @TheJeff this is too vague. Create a new post, add what you have tried and the issues you are facing.

Answer (score 11):

**Xcode 10.2.1**  **Swift 4**

Please add the following code in your **AppDelegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
            print("Playback OK")
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("Session is Active")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return true
    }
```

**Note: -** Please configure *options* as required. E.g to stop a background audio while a video file being played add

```
 options: [.allowAirPlay, .defaultToSpeaker]
```

And don't forget to enable audio and airplay in Background mode
[image]

Comment: You are a genius. This has been the only asnwer I have been able to find to make audio run in the background with a current swiftUI application. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Only paste on the viewDidload

[image]

```
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"Bismallah", ofType: "mp3")

    do{
        try playerr = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
    } catch {
        print("File is not Loaded")
    }
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do{
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    }
    catch{
    }

    player.play()
```

Comment: Excellent worked for me  only paste this code in viewdidload()

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5 Xcode 11.2.1**

Add this code where you have initialized the AudioPlayer.

```
audioPlayer.delegate = self
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do{
    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
}
catch{
    fatalError("playback failed")
}
```