# Running IOS Application in the Background new developer

Tags: ios, swift

I am new IOS developer using swift. I have created a Radio App (streams Live). **I want to make it to run in the background** when user minimize the app or do some other stuff. **Right now, it *stops* streaming audio as soon as sent to background** and continuous again as soon as it is brought to foreground.

I searched few articles and other forums, but couldn't find any help. I am really new to IOS development and don't know about controls/functions in the AppDelegate.swift.

So far I enabled the option under **Project Capabilities** Tab as following also made change in info.plist file, however Application still stops as soon as enters in the background.

[image: background modes enabled]

Any word of advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time and views.

Comment: i am also new, but just an idea...look into your AppDelegate file. Section `func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Play Audio in Background Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280519/how-to-play-audio-in-background-swift)

Comment: I am not aware of much about DidEnterBackground section and have hard time to understand the documentation at this point. @Leonardo looks like that is something different. 

Where do i have to paste that `var categoryError: NSError?
if AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: &categoryError) {` code ?

Comment: It can be at viewDidLoad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have adding the bool to info.plist file saying `"Application does not run in the background = "NO"`

Now I can run app in the background. I hope this solve the problem for others as well.