# AVAudioPlayer wont play sound when called in other swift file

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I have two swift files - my ViewController:UIViewController and AudioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer.

My AudioPlayer file has this function

```
func seaGullSound() {

    var tmp = AVAudioPlayer()

    var seaGullSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Gulls", ofType: "mp3")!)

    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

    var error:NSError?

    tmp = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: seaGullSound, error: &error)
    tmp.prepareToPlay()
    tmp.play()

    println("This function got called!")
}
```

I'm trying to call that function in my ViewController thru tapping a button, using this code:

```
@IBAction func playSound(sender: AnyObject) {
    var audio = AudioPlayer()
    audio.seaGullSound()
}
```

The sound is not played when I click the button. However, the print statement works. I can get the audio to play if I move seaGullSound() to the ViewController file, so I know the mp3 does work. I haven't moved the audio to ViewController because I want to develop the habit of not crowding all my code into one file. Thanks in advance for the help.

**edit:**

```
class HighScore: UIViewController {

var audioInitializer = AudioPlayer()

func updateHighScore(score:Int) -> String {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")

    //Check if score is higher than NSUserDefaults stored value and change NSUserDefaults stored value if it's true
    if score > NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore") {
        //call applause sound
        audioInitializer.applauseSound()
        //set score
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")

    //use below line to reset high score for testing
    //NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("highscore")

    return String(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore"))
}}
```

here is the file with the sounds:

```
class AudioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer {

var soundMaster = AVAudioPlayer()

func tappingSound() {

    var tapSoundURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("tapSound", withExtension: "mp3")

    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

    var error:NSError?

    soundMaster = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: tapSoundURL, error: &error)
    soundMaster.prepareToPlay()
    soundMaster.play()
}

//need to call in highscore.swift
func applauseSound() {
    var tapSoundURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("applause", withExtension: "mp3")

    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

    var error:NSError?

    soundMaster = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: tapSoundURL, error: &error)
    soundMaster.prepareToPlay()
    soundMaster.play()
    println("did this get called?")
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have move the declaration of your tmp AVAudioPlayer out of your method. Declare it as class variable.

You should also use URLForResource instead of pathForResource:

```
let seaGullSoundURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Gulls", withExtension:  "mp3")!
```

Try like this:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class HighScore: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func updateHighScore(score:Int) -> String {
        //Check if score is higher than NSUserDefaults stored value and change NSUserDefaults stored value if it's true
        if score > NSUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore") {
            //call applause sound
            playAudio("applause")
            //set score
            NSUserDefaults().setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
        }
        //use below line to reset high score for testing
        //NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("highscore")
        return NSUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore").description
    }
    func playAudio(audioName: String ) {
        var error:NSError?
        if let audioURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(audioName, withExtension: "mp3") {
            audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioURL, error: &error)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
        } else if let error = error {
            println(error.description)
        }
    }
    @IBAction func playSound(sender: UIButton) {
        playAudio("Gulls")
    }
}
```

Comment: wow thank you so much :) ... ill accept your answer in a couple minutes when im allowed to lol. and thanks for the quick response... would you explain why i have to call them at the class level?

Comment: if you declare it inside the method they will go out of existence when it ends the execution of the method

Comment: You should also take a look at this answer how to properly set AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback http://stackoverflow.com/a/30280699/2303865

Comment: interestingly enough im running into the same problem as before except with another file. ive followed your correction but it wont play the sound, but still executes the print statement

Comment: The file might be corrupted or with the wrong extension. Does it occurs with all sounds or just an specific one?

Comment: if it happens to all audio just add an edit to the question with your actual code I can review it for you.

Comment: it happens with all sounds

Comment: You don't not need a custom class to play sounds. You need just a method I will post one for you

Comment: Do you need your sound to playback while the app it is in the background?

Comment: @säculnój take a look at my edit and see if it helps you.

Comment: it still doesnt work.. i added a print statement to your code and it always prints just never plays any sound...

Comment: @säculnój do you have a github?