# How do I play the link in the AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting a link from itunes search api, and trying to pass it into an AVPlayer, but I am getting an error. http://puu.sh/ldBCw/6bfff69c7d.png. Below is the code to get the link.

```
 let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        do {
            if let dict: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            {


                    if let previewUrl = dict["results"]![0]["previewUrl"]  {
                        print(previewUrl!)
                         player = AVPlayer(URL: previewUrl)


                }

            }
        } catch let jsonError as NSError {

        }
    }
    task.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if let previewUrl = NSURL(string: dict["results"]![0]["previewUrl"])!  {
```

Also you could read it more here:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_8_Video_Playback_using_AVPlayer_and_AVPlayerViewController
and here: [How to Play Audio in Background Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280519/how-to-play-audio-in-background-swift)

Answer (score 0):

Use `player.play()` or `player.pause`. I used this in a recent project `let playerItem = AVPlayerItem( URL:NSURL( string:"Add your URL here" )! )
player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
player.rate = 1.0;
player.play()`