# Background music xcode 7 swift

Tags: audio, background, swift2, xcode7

I´ve already made an app but now I want to play background audio in my app when it launch with endless loop. I know it´s a dumb question but I would be happy if anybody can help me. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Play Audio in Background Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280519/how-to-play-audio-in-background-swift)

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question, but here is one example of what you can do.

Make sure you, above your class declaration, import the `AVFoundation` framework, like so:

```
import AVFoundation
```

If you have a `.mp3` file and you want to play it and loop it endlessly, you can use the following code to do so:

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func startAudio() {
    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("fileName", ofType: "mp3")
    let fileURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath!)
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOfURL: fileURL, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3)
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        audioPlayer.volume = 1
    } catch {
        self.presentViewController(UIAlertController.init(title: "Error", message: "Error Message", preferredStyle: .Alert), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

Call this function wherever you want in your controller and the audio should start playing. Hope this helps.

Comment: It works when I want to run it,thank you, but it is no volume this mean I can´t hear anything, I already type at the volume section at 100

Comment: The volume should be a floating point number between 0 and 1. Try setting it to `0.85` and see what happens please.

Comment: No, I'm sorry but it's still mute. I would be very happy if you can help me one more time. Thanks in advance