# How to track when song is finished AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avaudioplayer, audio-player

I want to track when playing song is finished. I tried different solutions from the web but they could not solve my problem. 
I implemented `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` method but it is not working. 
How can I understand if playing song is finished?

I am playing songs with `playSound` function

**playSound** **func:**

```
func playSound(name: String ) {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "mp3") else {
        print("url not found")
        return
    }

    do {
        /// this codes for making this app ready to takeover the device audio
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        /// change fileTypeHint according to the type of your audio file (you can omit this)
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3)
        // no need for prepareToPlay because prepareToPlay is happen automatically when calling play()
        player!.play()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

**audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying func:**

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    print("finished")//It is not working, not printing "finished"
}
```

How can I solve my problem? How to track when playing song is finished

**EDIT:** I am adding whole code.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift

import UIKit
import SwiftVideoBackground
import AudioToolbox
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController,AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundVideo: BackgroundVideo!

    @IBOutlet weak var initialLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var statementLabel: UILabel!


    var mp3: [String] = ["turk_milleti_demokrattir","xyz"]
    var fav: [String] = ["0","0"]
    var name: [String] = ["Türk milleti demokrattır","xy"]


    var toggleState = 1


    @IBOutlet weak var playB: UIButton!

    var counter = 0

    var duration = 0.1


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        player?.delegate = self

        playB.setImage(UIImage(named: "playbtn.png"), for: .normal)

        statementLabel.text = name[counter]

       backgroundVideo.createBackgroundVideo(name: "abc", type: "mp4")





    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func likeButton(_ sender: Any) {


        fav[counter] = "1"
        print(fav[0...1])


    }

    @IBAction func playButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let name = mp3[counter]
        playSound(name: name)


        let playBtn = sender as! UIButton
        if toggleState == 1 {
            player?.play()
            toggleState = 2
            playBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "pausebtn.png"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            player?.pause()
            toggleState = 1
            playBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"playbtn.png"),for: .normal)
        }  

    }


    @IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {

        counter = counter + 1

        if counter == mp3.count {
            counter = 0
        }

        toggleState = 2
        playB.setImage(UIImage(named: "pausebtn.png"), for: .normal)

        playSound(name: mp3[counter])

        statementLabel.text = name[counter]

    }





    func playSound(name: String ) {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "mp3") else {
            print("url not found")
            return
        }

        do {
            /// this codes for making this app ready to takeover the device audio
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            /// change fileTypeHint according to the type of your audio file (you can omit this)
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3)



            // no need for prepareToPlay because prepareToPlay is happen automatically when calling play()
            player!.play()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        print("finished")//It is not working, not printing "finished"
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you set your view controller the player delegate? `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`

Comment: I am newbie for iOS development - Swift. I do not know, How to set delegate?

Comment: You need to add AVAudioPlayerDelegate to your view controller declaration. `class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {`

Comment: I tried your solution but not working. Still, audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying is not working.

Comment: Are you sure you did set the correct view controller?

Comment: Yes I am sure but not working.

Comment: Please post your view controller actual code that it is not working

Comment: Ok, I am editing now.

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? The method it is not called? It doesn't print("finished")

Comment: BTW you should catch the error for every method that throws (try) https://stackoverflow.com/a/30280699/2303865

Comment: It does not print "finished", I edited my question.

Comment: Thankss... I solved my problem :) I am writing now as answer

Comment: It is not important the app will not be used by earphones.

Comment: Good to know you found the issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved my problem with help of [Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus).
I changed my edited code. I moved `player?.delegate = self`
to `playSound` func. Finally, it is working.

**playSound & audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying function:**

```
  func playSound(name: String ) {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "mp3") else {
            print("url not found")
            return
        }

        do {
            /// this codes for making this app ready to takeover the device audio
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            /// change fileTypeHint according to the type of your audio file (you can omit this)
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3)

            player?.delegate = self

            // no need for prepareToPlay because prepareToPlay is happen automatically when calling play()
            player!.play()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        print("finished")//It is working now! printed "finished"!
    }
```

Do not forget to add `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` to ViewController!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
```

Comment: I was about to write up that same instruction when I saw another answer posted, and it looks like you figured it out. On behalf of SO, thanks for taking the time to post the solution back to the thread.

Answer (score 3):

You are not setting the player's delegate correctly.

In viewDidLoad, your player is going to be nil, so this line:

```
    player?.delegate = self
```

Will do nothing (The question mark is optional chaining, so if player == nil, it does nothing.)

You need to set the delegate after loading the player.

Comment: Even better, put that assignment in the `player`'s `didSet` block.

Comment: @NRitH, Good suggestion.

Comment: :D :D :D Hi, Duncan!

Comment: @NRitH Lead Belly! I didn't recognize you!