# iOS Background Execution - playing audio and making network calls

Tags: ios, audio, avplayer, multitasking

I have a simple task - play audio and fetch the information from the network while **possibly being in the background**.

My app uses own backend which keeps, say, playlist DB (which might dynamically change). The app fetches the URL of the next song stream that it needs to play from the DB and starts playing it. Then the user presses home button and the app goes to background. The audio should continue playing the music and there are numerous tutorials and articles on how to do that. However, during the playback in the background my app should periodically update the playlist and fetch it from the backend to know what is the next song to play. If the playback in the background is handled by the system, then how should I run this extra data fetching code in the background? *For fetching I don't use URL Session, I use higher level abstractions from the backend provider SDKs (like Parse server SDKs or some AWS SDKs).*

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280519/how-to-play-audio-in-background-swift?rq=1

Comment: Well playing in the background is not a problem, the problem is connecting to my backend while playing in the background... so that I know what to play next.