# IOS How to play music sound in background and pause current playing music app

Tags: ios, audio, background

I am trying to play a sound file when app is already in background AND stop current play music app if it is playing on iOS

Could you please tell me how can i do that

Many thanks,

William Tran.

Answer (score 2):

iOS will automatically pause other audio instances if your app begins one. Check out this thread: [How to Play Audio in Background Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280519/how-to-play-audio-in-background-swift)

Comment: I am using Objective C. My script as below:




AVAudioSession *avSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        NSError* __autoreleasing err = nil;
        
        [avSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&err];
        
        err = nil;
        [avSession setActive:YES error:&err];
        
    
        self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soudnUrl
                                                                      error:NULL];
       
        [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [audioPlayer play];
BUT IT DID NOT WORK

Answer (score 0):

i found out the reason for my issue:
 The operation couldn?t be completed. (OSStatus error 560557684.)

Because my app init and active an audio session when it is already in background that's why we could not do that.

Comment: Facing the same issue? Any suggestion on what I do next? Thanks!